# Simple change the active tab in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, tabs

So I can't seem to change the tab in chrome using the code below. All I am trying to do at the moment is change the active tab any other tab via clicking on the extension icon, but that doesn't seem to work. My manifest file has all the correct permissions and the format is fine, so this code in the banckground.js file must be wrong somehow. Thanks.

```
 chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.update(tab[2].id, {selected: true});
});
```

Comment: Probably because its deprecated: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#property-updateProperties-selected

Answer (score -1):

use:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

//..your tab changing code..

});
```

Comment: Is this applicable to the browser 'chrome' in Chrome?